# Issue with the definition of differential privacy

Tags: differential-privacy

The definition of differential privacy states that if $\mathcal{M}$ is  $(\epsilon,\delta)$-differentially private, then $\forall x,y$ such that $||x-y||_1\leq1$ and for all $S \subseteq \mathrm{Range}(\mathcal{M})$:

$$\mathrm{Pr}(M(x)\in S) \leq e^\epsilon \mathrm{Pr}(M(y)\in S) + \delta. $$

Now, suppose you were able to show that for any outcome $s_i$ (single element) that $\mathcal{M}$ was $(\epsilon,\delta)$-differentially private, i.e., $\mathrm{Pr}(M(x)= s_i) \leq e^\epsilon \mathrm{Pr}(M(y)= s_i) + \delta $. Then for a set $S=\cup_i s_i$, since $\mathrm{Pr}(M(x)\in S) = \sum_i \mathrm{Pr}(M(x)=s_i)$, we have that:

$$\sum_i \mathrm{Pr}(M(x)=s_i) \leq  e^\epsilon \sum_i \mathrm{Pr}(M(y)=s_i) + |S| \delta \implies$$
$$\mathrm{Pr}(M(x)\in S) \leq  e^\epsilon \mathrm{Pr}(M(y) \in S) + |S| \delta$$

The above is fine if we have $(\epsilon,0)$ with $\delta=0$, but non-zero delta causes a problem. There is a one to one corresponds between proving differential privacy over a single element and a set in the case when $\delta=0$. But the definition doesn't make sense to me for $\delta \neq 0$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that a mechanism/algorithm is $(\epsilon,\delta)$-differentially private you would have to show that the inequality holds for all subsets (technically all measurable subsets, which matters if the output is continuous).

So if you are in a situation where all you can show is that for single outputs $s$ that the inequality holds for some $\delta > 0$ then you might, as you see, have a hard time stitching together the same guarantee for all subsets. In most cases, however, you won't need to build up the result like that.

An intuition behind the parameter $\delta$ is that it is the probability that the stronger $(\epsilon,0)$ guarantee fails to hold. That is, the probability of producing an $s$ such that for some neighboring $y$ the bound fails to hold.

A related concept are *composition bounds*, which are used to analyze the aggregate privacy risk of releases from a collection of $(\epsilon,\delta)$-differentially private mechanisms. Composition bounds give an *upper bound* on the total privacy risk. However each individual risk has to satisfy the bound for all measurable subsets in the range of the mechanism.